# select the joined entity only via query builder

Tags: doctrine-orm, query-builder

consider the following expression of query builder in doctrine.

```
# fail
$em->createQueryBuilder()->select('m')->from('TbUsermanager','t')
                ->join('t.manager', 'm')
                ->where('t.user=:user')
                ->setParameter('user', 1)
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();

# success
$em->createQueryBuilder()->select('t')->from('TbUsermanager','t')
                ->join('t.manager', 'm')
                ->where('t.user=:user')
                ->setParameter('user', 1)
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();
```

The object `TbUsermanager` is the relation table between `TbUser` and `TbManager`.

The annotation of them is

```
# user
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TbUser")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="ID")
     * })

# manager
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TbManager")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="manager_id", referencedColumnName="ID")
     * })
```

However, why I can't just select the manager objects? How can I do that? I tried m.id, it works fine.

**update:**
in the `# fail` query, I expect it returns the collection of object `TbManager`, however, it throws the following exception

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException' with message 'SELECT m FROM TbUsermanager t INNER JOIN t.manager m WHERE t.user = 1' in C:\php_projects\zms_core\wcms\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException.php:41
```

If I change `select('m')` to `select('m.id')` which will return the collection of TbManager ids works fine.

Comment: Please provide more information. "Doesn't work" is not a good description. What did you expect? What happened instead? What kind of error message did you get?

Comment: @xabbuh thanks, I have updated the question and post the error.

Answer (score 0):

The complete error message will contain something like this message:

> Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias.

The reason for this is that Doctrine expects you to select data from the main entity your query is based on (which in your example is `TbUsermanager`).

A possible solution is to just change the entity from which to select:

```
SELECT m
FROM TbManager AS m
JOIN TbUsermanager AS t WITH t.manager = m
WHERE t.user = :user
```

`WITH` can be used to restrict a join clause (in case you can build the join based on an entity's property) or to give the join condition at all.